# jenkins can't trigger build on pull request from bitbucket cloud

Tags: jenkins

i need to trigger the job in jenkins when user raise the pull request to bitbucket cloud. I added repo url with credential.i added to refspec :+refs/pull-requests/*/from:refs/remotes/* and branch specifier : **/pull-requests/**...i update the build triggers with option bitbucket pull request builder, Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket and poll scm (*****).. I have added the public key in bitbucket cloud whereas added private key in jenkins server. I added the jenkins url with job name (http://jenkinsurl:8080/jobname) in bitbucket webhooks..but still cant trigger the job when user raise on pull request from bitbucket...i dont know where im wrong? guide me.what are the steps should perform for this?guide me anyone.

Comment: In Bitbucket you should see the status of webhook requests sent to Jenkins. Is their status HTTP 200 ? Also, please post some screenshots of how your job is configured in Jenkins

Comment: how to add screen shot to here. if any one have document or link about jenkins integration with bitbucket cloud. i tried lot..but couldn't..post here or whatsapp me +91 7448719202

Comment: See https://mohamicorp.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOC/pages/121274372/Configuring+Webhook+To+Jenkins+for+Bitbucket

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had a similar issue and managed to solve it with this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47889853/10235273